# How can a Ssl Server(Https) block connections?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate

**This is Client side related.**

I'm currently doing research work. I need to connect to a Server(https),but somehow I'm unable to connect to It. (It's an Apache Server)

If I try to connect like this:

```
//Load Certificate          
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"some.cer");
//Set Callback
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;
//Create Request + assign Cert, Cert is not null
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myserver.com");
        if (cert != null)
            req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
//Process Request
        try
        {
            req.Timeout = 10000;
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

I end up with an exception thrown because of a Timeout. As you can see I'm loading a custom certificate here. I'm not 100% sure If It's right but It seems to be right.

So the problem is It can't even establish a connection. There's just a timeout and the assigned callback is never called.

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. I'm like 90% sure the Certificate is right. Are there other methods to block unwanted clients or do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe there are firewalls between you and the server?

Comment: Do mean you firewalls which explicity block my Ip? From what I know is they have a Gateway Server and resolve the requests down to the specific Server. Also If you talk about Ip related blocks There are no Ip blocks. At least not for my Ip I'm 100% sure.

Comment: It may not be based on IP. It could be based on protocol or anything else. Do you have any other code that can talk to that server? Better still, code that can talk to that server over SSL?

Comment: I'm analysing an App I'm kinda sure the Tcp Protocol is used. The Application Itself can access anything from my Pc. Im abit tired right now. But probably I can check the flags in Winsock connect to figure out if the problem is there. But seriously I dont believe the protocol is different as similar Apps by the same Provider also work with Tcp + Http(s).

Comment: I mean browse to the server using a web browser over https. If you can do that, then there's no (simple) firewall blocking. There could still be a sophisticated firewall, the kind that can block different applications differently.

Comment: I cannt browse It with a Web Browser. Curl,Python,etc all fails to etablish a connection. The Server basicly doesnt even respond and not anything is sent at all.

Comment: That sounds like a firewall or a server problem, not a problem with your code, since there is _no_ program which can connect over SSL. The server may even be turned off!

Comment: You'd better capture some network packets, via Wireshark or any other tools. Then you can analyze the SSL handshakes to see what's up. Just review the code is far from enough. If you are not capable of such troubleshooting, find a network expert or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: I captured packets with Wireshark now. Somehow the client sends the first handshake after this 2 retransmissions are send by the client. The server doesnt even respond. Unfourtanely I cannt access the pc with the App today. I'll have to wait for tommorow to see whats different in the handshake. I'll report what I figured out. Still thanks for the help so far.